# Find $f:\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where the mean value theorem fails

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, examples-counterexamples, monotone-functions

Find a differentiable function $f:\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is not monotonically increasing, but still fullfills $f'(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Q}$.

---

The background of this problem is that functions from the rationals to the reals have different properties than the ones analyzed in real analysis. According to the exercise sheet, differentiability still implies continuity in a non-complete vector space, but the mean value theorem does not hold (hence the problem above).

I blindly tried few functions, but I don't quite get why the mean value theorem shouldn't hold. Thank you for helping me.

---

Source: This problem is taken from my analysis course. However, this was not homework and I'm going back the exercise sheets to prepare for the exam. Link for anyone interested (German), the problem is "Aufgabe 1.B (a)": https://www.mathematik.hu-berlin.de/~wendl/Sommer2019/Analysis2/Blatt1.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just take $f(x)=\dfrac1{\sqrt2-x}$. That will work.

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is actually very clever. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest example might be

$$ f(x)=\begin{cases} 1, & x^2<2,\\ 0, & x^2>2.\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This functions works and I wouldn't have thought of it.

Answer (score 1):

Try 
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $x < \sqrt{2}$} \\
0 & \text{if $x > \sqrt{2}$}
\end{cases}
$$
This not only satisfies your criterion, but $f'(x)=0$ for all $x \in \mathbb Q$, and yet $f$ is *not constant!*.

Comment: This is at the same time the solution to the next exercise on the sheet too. I wouldn't have thought of it. Thanks a lot!